# Python : Control the number of variations entered by user

Tags: python

I have a script where the user decides how many titles or images he wants to enter. The maximum is 3 titles and 3 images and my script should create unique variations of the titles and images. If the user enters 3 titles 2 images, my script should create 6 variations:

```
Title1 + image1
Title1 + image2
Title2 + image1
Title2 + image2
Title3 + image1
Title3 + image2
```

Here is my code that is working ok but I was wondering if there is a lighter way to handle this case figure:

```
titleNbr = 3
imageNbr = 3

if titleNbr == 1 and imageNbr == 1:
    print("No variation")

if titleNbr == 1 and imageNbr == 2:
    print("Variations : Title1 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title1 + image2")

if titleNbr == 1 and imageNbr == 3:
    print("Variations : Title1 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title1 + image2")
    print("Variations : Title1 + image3")

if titleNbr == 2 and imageNbr == 1:
    print("Variations : Title1 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image1")

if titleNbr == 2 and imageNbr == 2:
    print("Variations : Title1 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title1 + image2")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image2")

if titleNbr == 2 and imageNbr == 3:
    print("Variations : Title1 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title1 + image2")
    print("Variations : Title1 + image3")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image2")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image3")

if titleNbr == 3 and imageNbr == 1:
    print("Variations : Title1 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title3 + image1")

if titleNbr == 3 and imageNbr == 2:
    print("Variations : Title1 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title1 + image2")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image2")
    print("Variations : Title3 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title3 + image2")

if titleNbr == 3 and imageNbr == 3:
    print("Variations : Title1 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title1 + image2")
    print("Variations : Title1 + image3")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image2")
    print("Variations : Title2 + image3")
    print("Variations : Title3 + image1")
    print("Variations : Title3 + image2")
    print("Variations : Title3 + image3")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by iterating from 1 to the title number and then from one to the image number, and just appending this number to your strings. For example:

```
titleNbr = 3
imageNbr = 3

if titleNbr == 1 and imageNbr == 1:
    print("No variation")
else:   
    for i in range(1, titleNbr + 1):
        for j in range(1, imageNbr + 1):
            print("Variations : Title" + str(i) + " + image" + str(j))
```

Let me know if you need clarification on any parts of this code!